# "Union" Multiple Select Query in Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I trying to "Union" multiple select statements in below Stored Procedure

```
Create or replace PROCEDURE procedure1
as
BEGIN
SELECT b.EntityName,
     c.StateLaneName,
              c.ConsiderEntityOwnership,
              a.InitialState,
     d.StateName,
     e.EventName,
     1              AS Discriminator,     
     NULL               AS TransitionSeq,
     NULL               AS TransitionName,
     k.WorkflowActionSeq        AS ActionSeq,
     l.ActionName           AS ActionName,
     l.ClassPath            AS ClassPath,
     NULL               AS MessageKey,
     NULL               AS NextStateName

   FROM Workflow a,
     Entity b,
     WorkflowStateLane c,
     WorkflowState d,
     WorkflowEvent e,
     WorkflowEventAction k,
     WorkflowAction l

WHERE a.WorkflowEntityId        = b.EntityId
      AND a.WorkflowStateLaneId     = c.WorkflowStateLaneId
      AND a.WorkflowStateId     = d.WorkflowStateId
      AND a.WorkflowEventId     = e.WorkflowEventId
      AND a.WorkflowId          = k.WorkflowId
      AND k.WorkflowActionId        = l.WorkflowActionId
      AND k.TransitionActionType        = 1

UNION

(SELECT b.EntityName,
     c.StateLaneName,
              c.ConsiderEntityOwnership,
              a.InitialState,
     d.StateName,
     e.EventName,
     2              AS Discriminator,    
     NULL               AS TransitionSeq,
     NULL               AS TransitionName,
     k.WorkflowActionSeq        AS ActionSeq,
     l.ActionName           AS ActionName,
     l.ClassPath            AS ClassPath,
     NULL               AS MessageKey,
     NULL               AS NextStateName

   FROM Workflow a,
     Entity b,
     WorkflowStateLane c,
     WorkflowState d,
     WorkflowEvent e,
     WorkflowEventAction k,
     WorkflowAction l

WHERE a.WorkflowEntityId        = b.EntityId
      AND a.WorkflowStateLaneId     = c.WorkflowStateLaneId
      AND a.WorkflowStateId     = d.WorkflowStateId
      AND a.WorkflowEventId     = e.WorkflowEventId
      AND a.WorkflowId          = k.WorkflowId
      AND k.WorkflowActionId        = l.WorkflowActionId
      AND k.TransitionActionType        = 2);
END proceure1;
```

When I compile I'm getting an error
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this select function.
I'm newbie in Oracle. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

In PL/SQL, the result of a SELECT query needs to go somewhere. So either you use it in a loop:

```
FOR rec in (
    SELECT a, b FROM t
) LOOP
   -- do something with rec.a and rec.b
END LOOP;
```

Or you have to use the INTO clause to assign it to variables:

```
DECLARE
  l_a NUMBER;
  l_b VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  SELECT a, b INTO l_a, l_b FROM t;
  -- do something with l_a and l_b
END;
```

Your SELECT statement is probably fine if you run it in TOAD or SQL Developer. But in PL/SQL you need to apply one of the two patterns above.

Comment: So if u go for the latter option, i need to make so many declaration is it??

Comment: Yes, in the latter option, you need to declare a variable for each column you retrieve. However, that solution only works if you retrieve a single row. Since the introduction of your question talks about UNION you'll probably retrieve several rows. Then you need a different approach. What do you want to do with the retrieved data?

Comment: Yes multiple rows is generated. Could you please explain that approach. Trying to union tables with different TransitionActionType and Discriminator columns from the table

Comment: What do you want to do with the retrieved data?

Comment: Merge and compare datas

Answer (score 0):

Because the select-union will output multiple rows you'll need to use `open for` like this:

```
Create or replace PROCEDURE procedure1 (
  p_cursor out sys_refcursor
) as
BEGIN
open p_cursor for
SELECT b.EntityName,
     c.StateLaneName,
              c.ConsiderEntityOwnership,
              a.InitialState,
     d.StateName,
     e.EventName,
     1              AS Discriminator,     
     NULL               AS TransitionSeq,
     NULL               AS TransitionName,
     k.WorkflowActionSeq        AS ActionSeq,
     l.ActionName           AS ActionName,
     l.ClassPath            AS ClassPath,
     NULL               AS MessageKey,
     NULL               AS NextStateName

   FROM Workflow a,
     Entity b,
     WorkflowStateLane c,
     WorkflowState d,
     WorkflowEvent e,
     WorkflowEventAction k,
     WorkflowAction l

WHERE a.WorkflowEntityId        = b.EntityId
      AND a.WorkflowStateLaneId     = c.WorkflowStateLaneId
      AND a.WorkflowStateId     = d.WorkflowStateId
      AND a.WorkflowEventId     = e.WorkflowEventId
      AND a.WorkflowId          = k.WorkflowId
      AND k.WorkflowActionId        = l.WorkflowActionId
      AND k.TransitionActionType        = 1

UNION

(SELECT b.EntityName,
     c.StateLaneName,
              c.ConsiderEntityOwnership,
              a.InitialState,
     d.StateName,
     e.EventName,
     2              AS Discriminator,    
     NULL               AS TransitionSeq,
     NULL               AS TransitionName,
     k.WorkflowActionSeq        AS ActionSeq,
     l.ActionName           AS ActionName,
     l.ClassPath            AS ClassPath,
     NULL               AS MessageKey,
     NULL               AS NextStateName

   FROM Workflow a,
     Entity b,
     WorkflowStateLane c,
     WorkflowState d,
     WorkflowEvent e,
     WorkflowEventAction k,
     WorkflowAction l

WHERE a.WorkflowEntityId        = b.EntityId
      AND a.WorkflowStateLaneId     = c.WorkflowStateLaneId
      AND a.WorkflowStateId     = d.WorkflowStateId
      AND a.WorkflowEventId     = e.WorkflowEventId
      AND a.WorkflowId          = k.WorkflowId
      AND k.WorkflowActionId        = l.WorkflowActionId
      AND k.TransitionActionType        = 2);
END proceure1;
```